# Can raspberry Pi support TWI communication?

Tags: i2c, signal

I have an image sensor MT9V034-D, which is manufactured by onsemi. It is supposed to be controlled by TWI with a SCLK and SDA input, I want to use Raspberry Pi to control it.

I know that Raspberry Pi supports I2C, and I2C is roughly compatible with TWI, so the question is, can I use Raspberry Pi to control a TWI device? Can I just set the communication method like I2C?